# Why is this simple MSMQ Transaction escalated to DTC?

Tags: msmq, message-queue, transactionscope

I have reduced a problem I'm having to the following example code:

```
var inQueue = ".\private$\testqueue";
using (var ts = new TransactionScope())
{
    using (var q = new MessageQueue(inQueue, QueueAccessMode.Send))
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < 100000; ++i)
        {
            var msg = new Message(i);
            q.Send(msg, MessageQueueTransactionType.Automatic);
        }
    }
    ts.Complete();
}
```

As you can see, all it does it write 100,000 integers to a (transactional, local) queue using the TransactionScope pattern. My understanding is that this type of operation would not escalate to a DTC transaction.

However, if I open up Component Services while this is running, I can see the transaction in the Local DTC > Transaction List. This means that the transaction has been escalated, right?

Why would this be happening? I was prompted to this by bad performance in another program, and it would appear that the use of DTC for such a simple transaction may be a factor. Regardless, I just want to understand the cause.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From http://geekswithblogs.net/dotnetrodent/archive/2008/04/16/121279.aspx

> If you only need to do transactional work related to message queues,
>   without any other resources that need to be in the transactional
>   context (like databases), don’t use the TransactionScope, but rather
>   the [MessageQueueTransaction class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.messagequeuetransaction.aspx). Using this
>   class to control transactions related only to message queues comes
>   with a lesser performance penalty than using a full distributed
>   transaction controlled by DTC.

Comment: It's not what I wanted to hear, but it does appear to be the answer. I was under the impression that TransactionScope would handle either, as it does with SQL transactions but it would appear not. Oh well. Thanks for your reply.